# Filling a String in to different cells

Tags: vba, excel

I want to fill a series of cells with a Array but I am unable to do it.

**1)**

```
Dim Principal() As String
Dim txt As String

For i = LBound(Principal) To UBound(Principal)
    txt = txt & Principal(i)  & vbCrLf
Next i
MsgBox txt
```

**2)**

```
Dim Principal() As String
Dim txt As String

For i = LBound(Principal) To UBound(Principal)
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3) = Principal(i)
Next i
```

I can see the output in the first example i.e MsgBox but I get an error when I try to store in to different cells. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible your array starts at 0, where cells(0,3) cannot be found?

Comment: Use Option Base 1 in your module to make arrays start at index 1

Comment: @Alex Thanks Alex. That was quick and you are right. i+1 works .

Comment: @Meesha welcome!  You can consider Sorceri's suggestion - using option base 1, and pay attention on the array's input.

Comment: @Alex You might want to add that as answer with some other tips in arrays.

Answer (score 3):

Alex and Sorceri already pointed out that by default, arrays start at index 0.
 But aside from that, you don't need to loop to pass your array to range.

```
' 1D Array
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("C1:C" & Ubound(Principal) + 1) = Application.Transpose(Principal)
End With
```

Take note of the `+ 1`. If `Option Base = 1` then you'll have to remove it.
Also take note that if you're passing 1D array to range, you'll need to `Transpose` the array.